# Cancel a previous axios request on new request in Vue Js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I am trying to implement a search which loads user data from the backend on every word change using @input and populate in datalist, now for every change a new request is generated while the old request is still processing/pending this causes some problems. I am looking to cancel old request on every new request that will take place.

Html code in vue js

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Name"  v-model="forms.name" list="getname"  @input="inputData()" required> <datalist id="getInput" > <option v-for="option in options">{{option}}</option> </datalist>
```

Function to load data

```
axios.get('Url/GetUser/'+ this.forms.name).then((response) => {if(response.data.error){ this.errorNya = response.data; this.loading2 = false;}else{ this.errorNya.username = ""; this.options = response.data; this.loading2= false; this.disableButton = true; }
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at [axios/docs/cancellation](https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation)?

Comment: What about searching the data at client side ? It will increase the performance and will save server operations on each @input.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal Doesn't fit the context, if there are so few users it's reasonable to fetch them at once, there's hardly the need for search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have referred the documentation and other sources for this question, and i found a solution which suited me best.

```
this.cancelFunc();
//Below line creates a cancel token for this request 
let axiosSource = axios.CancelToken.source();

this.request = { cancel: axiosSource.cancel };

//then we pass the token to the request we want to cancel.
axios.get('/Url/GetUser/'+ this.forms.username, {cancelToken: axiosSource.token,}).then((response) => {
    if (response.data.error) {
        this.errorNya = response.data;
        this.loading2 = false;
    } else {
        this.errorNya.username = "";
        this.options = response.data;
        this.loading2 = false;
        this.disableButton = true;
    }
},
    cancelFunc() {
        if (this.request) 
        this.request.cancel();
      },
```

i know this will not be the best way to do this, but this solved my problem.